# How can we connect to an SFTP server from a Windows machine to a Linux SFTP server using a DSA key?

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, sftp

As a Windows user, I generated a pair of DSA keys from CoreFTP Lite and sent it to a third party that runs an SFTP server.

They told me that a valid DSA key needs to have ssh-dsa at the start and the username@systemname at the end.

CoreFTP generated neither the ssh-dsa header nor the username@systemname footer. I tried with WinSCP and it didn't generate them either.

Is there a difference between how SFTP works between Windows and Linux?

If I put a useraccount@systemname at the end of the text will it work? How would the Linux system validate that my system is called "systemname"? If it can't validate, what is the purpose of adding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a difference between how SFTP works between Windows and Linux?

No. The only difference is *key storage formats* used by various programs. Most Linux systems run OpenSSH as the SSH/SFTP server, and your third party is requesting an OpenSSH-compatible public key.

- **CoreFTP** stores private keys in the OpenSSH format, and public keys in a similar to OpenSSH.

  You can use PuTTYgen or `ssh-keygen -yf` to extract the public key, as the "private" file always contains the entire keypair.

  Or you can simply **add "`ssh-dss`" before the CoreFTP public key data** to make it OpenSSH-compatible. Example:

  ```
  ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3M...
  ```

  (Why does CoreFTP forget the header? It could be that the developers deemed it unnecessary, as the Base64-encoded data already has `ssh-dss` in the beginning. And besides, who would *ever* need compatibility with the most popular SFTP software?)
- **PuTTY** uses its own "PPK" key format.

  When you open the key in PuTTYgen (or generate a fresh one), the OpenSSH *public* key is **displayed in the big box at the top.**

  The *private* key can be exported to OpenSSH format through the menus.
- **WinSCP** does not have a key generation program. It bundles PuTTYgen from PuTTY.

For completeness:

- **OpenSSH** (`ssh`, `ssh-keygen`) stores private keys in "PEM" format used by OpenSSL, and public keys in its own single-line format. (As mentioned above, the "private" key file contains both private and public keys.)

---

> They told me that a valid DSA key needs to have [...] the username@systemname at the end.
>
> [...] If I put a useraccount@systemname at the end of the text will it work? How would the Linux system validate that my system is called "systemname"? If it can't validate, what is the purpose of adding it?

The `username@systemname` part is a *comment* used for key identification (for example, when you have 10 keys in *authorized_keys*), but is **entirely ignored by software.**

OpenSSH public keys without a comment are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the public part of your key pair in a format that the third party's SFTP server can recognise - and in this case, it looks like they want the openssh format.

I'm no expert on the format of CoreFTP Lite dsa keys, but from some random google hits, it looks like you can use [PuttyGen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to open the key generated by CoreFTP, then export it as an OpenSSH public key.